# Populate Table in Word document template with table using C#

Tags: c#, .net, templates, ms-word

I created a .dot, and put a simple table. The fields, TESTE_1 and TESTE_2 are from "Quick Parts >> Field " I want to populate this table from database (external files, or whatever) using C# Code.

[image]

I put a "MergeField" in the table cells (Test1). There a lot of codes showing how to "find and replace" these bookmarks, But how to fill a table I not found, like:

`Column1 | Column2 
 Foo     | Bar 
 Zee     | Top.`

Comment: You need to provide more information - your question is currently to borad and inexact. For starters: 1) Please provide more detail (including code) how you "replace text" (whether in a table or not). 2) Please describe the table structure you show us: what is the shaded <<TESTE_1>>, exactly? 3) Are you creating this template or is someone providing it and you need to work with that? (Or is this some kind of school project...)

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister.

I created a .dot, and put a simple table.

The fields, TESTE_1 and TESTE_2 are from "Quick Parts >> Field "

I want to populate this table from C# Code. Looking in internet I just found how to replace text.

Comment: What kind of field? There are many, many kinds of fields... However, if what you want is a "target" for writing to the document you can use either BOOKMARKS (Insert tab) or CONTENT CONTROLS (Developer tab). Since they're older, you'll find a lot more code examples for Bookmarks when you search.

Comment: You're alright  @CindyMeister.
I put a "MergeField".
There a lot of codes showing how to "find and replace" these bookmarks.
And I want to fiil a table like:

`Column1 | Column2
Foo         | Bar
Zee         | Top`

Comment: Yes, I'll extract datas from SQL Server

Comment: I'm afraid I can't chat at the moment - it's the end of my day. Outlining the approach, however: Select the table and insert a bookmark. Now you can pick up the table from the bookmark and work with the individual cells, add rows, etc.: Word.Table tbl = Doc.Bookmarks.get_item("Name").Range.Tables[1]; Let me know how you get on...

Comment: Sorry for "chat", I click on wrong button.
Thanks a lot for your help. I'll see and test.

Comment: No problems for "chat" - the site is prompting us :-) Here's an article that will help you working with tables in Word. It also discusses performance:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537149%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 If this information has helped you I'll consolidate it into an "Answer" and we can delete that series of comments so that site administration is happier :-)

Comment: Yes. It helped me (a lot).
I had never worked in this area, And I was so lost.
What I've done was: I put a Bookmark at table and manipulate as I wanted.
I thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: OK, I've consolidated your information by editing the original and my information in an Answer. We can probably delete a few of the comments, if you're comfortable with that.

Comment: MS Word fields and mail merge feature are useful for one-to-one bindings but for many-to-one binding they are not a good fit. Instead, **insert a bookmark in the header row and dynamically add the rows to the Word table**. Here is a working solution: [Insert rows to table dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76504503/2638227).

Answer (score 1):

Since your main problem is how to locate the table in the document, then work with it:

1. Select the table and insert a Bookmark around it. This will allow your code to pick up the table directly:

   Word.Table tbl = Doc.Bookmarks.get_item("Name").Range.Tables[1];
2. Here's an article that will help you working with tables in Word. It also discusses performance issues: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537149%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396