# Error in loop action with word automation

Tags: c#

I am trying to export data from database to word document. But it breaks in the loop action. How can we loop multiple rows? It works very well without loop. But when it loops, it gives error.
It reads the first row in the database correctly. It gives an error while reading the next row.

[image: Error image]

```
int iTotalFields = 0;
Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Object oTrue = true;
Object oFalse = false;
Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();

oWord.Visible = true;
Object oTemplatePath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\GeziListesi.docx";
oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

foreach(Word.Field myMergeField in oWordDoc.Fields) {
    iTotalFields++;

    Word.Range rngFieldCode = myMergeField.Code;
    String fieldText = rngFieldCode.Text;

    if (fieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD")) {
        Int32 endMerge = fieldText.IndexOf("\\");
        Int32 fieldNameLength = fieldText.Length - endMerge;
        String fieldName = fieldText.Substring(11, endMerge - 11);

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=gezievrak2541.mdb; Mode = ReadWrite");

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) {
            conn.Open();
        }

        using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from gezibilgileri25", conn)) {
            using(OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
                while (dr.Read()) {

                    fieldName = fieldName.Trim();

                   

                    if (fieldName == "tcno") {
                        myMergeField.Select();
                        oWord.Selection.TypeText(dr["tcno"].ToString());
                    }
                    if (fieldName == "adsoyad") {
                        myMergeField.Select();
                        oWord.Selection.TypeText(dr["adi"].ToString() + " " + dr["soyadi"].ToString());
                    }
                    if (fieldName != "sinifi") {
                        //myMergeField.Select();
                        oWord.Selection.TypeText(" ");

                    }
                    if (fieldName == ("sinifi")) {
                        myMergeField.Select();
                        oWord.Selection.TypeText(dr["sinifi"].ToString());
                    }

                    if (fieldName == "unvan") {
                        myMergeField.Select();
                        oWord.Selection.TypeText(dr["unvani"].ToString());
                    }                 
                    }
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `GC.Collect`, and why !twice!? What do you see when you debug this?

Comment: By the way, calling `GC.Collect` the way you are will greatly slow down your application. By calling it multiple time (twice, each pass through a loop!), you are pushing all active objects into `Gen2`, meaning that every collection will be a (much slower) Gen2 collection. Generally you should not be calling `GC.Collect` on your own (the GC is pretty good at figuring out when to make the call). An exception is at the end of a section where you've done a lot of work, when the objects you've been working with are no longer being used, and your app is likely to be mostly dormant for a while

Comment: Since you are "typing" over the top of the selection, `myMergeField.Select();` is going to be an invalid reference on subsequent loops. IMHO check the field name and select the field once. Then select only the column you need. Then replace the text.

Comment: My problem isn't that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Word *fields* and *mail merge feature* are useful for one-to-one bindings but for many-to-one binding never mind them. **Instead, insert a bookmark in the header row and dynamically add the rows to the Word table**. First follow these steps:

1. Adapt your MS Word document, namely *GeziListesi.doc*, to look similar to the image below.
2. Put the mouse cursor at the end of the header row as in the image.
   [image]
3. In MS Word select Insert > Bookmark.
4. In the Bookmark dialog, add a bookmark with name *StudentList*. (Used in the code)

Now use the following class:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordOle
{
    internal class WordAutomation
    {
        public void WriteToWord()
        {
            DataTable dt = GetDataSource();

            object oMissing = Missing.Value;
            Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
            oWord.Visible = true;
            object oTemplatePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\GeziListesi.doc";
            Word.Document oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            object Index = "StudentList";
            Word.Table tbl = oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref Index).Range.Tables[1];

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Word.Row newRow = tbl.Rows.Add(ref oMissing);
                for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    newRow.Cells[j].Range.Text = dr[j - 1].ToString();
                }
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tbl);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWordDoc);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWord);
        }

        private DataTable GetDataSource()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=gezievrak2541.mdb; Mode = ReadWrite"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from gezibilgileri25", conn))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I wrote a separate method `GetDataSource()` to pull the MS Access data first. Performing two different tasks (getting the data and writing to Word) in a single method is a bad programming practice.

Comment: I tried your code. But it gives this error "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Grupta istenen bir eleman yok.'" in the line Word.Table tbl = oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref Index).Range.Tables[1];

Comment: It seems `oWordDoc.Bookmarks` is null or empty. Did you add the bookmark *StudentList* to your document?

Comment: Or `.Range.Tables` may be null or empty. Check them.

Comment: Yes, I am adding the bookmark like that: 1.Select or highlight a location, picture, or text in your document.  
2. In the "Insert" tab on the ribbon menu, within the "Links" group select "Bookmark."
3. Type a name for your bookmark and click "Add." 
4. To create a link to the bookmark (such as in a list or table of contents at the top of the document), highlight the text you'd like it to link from and "Hyperlink" from the "Insert" tab.
5. Select "Place in This Document" from the left pane, expand "Bookmarks" to select the desired bookmark to link, and click "OK."

Comment: The first 3 of your steps are enough to add the *StudentList* bookmark. No need to perform the next steps. To make things clear, put a breakpoint in the `Word.Table tbl = oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref Index).Range.Tables[1]` line and inspect the `oWordDoc.Bookmarks` and `Range.Tables` collections. Both must be non-null for the code to work correctly. I have tested my code and can generate the Word output correctly.

Comment: How can we put a breakpoint? I can't succeed it. Please can you tell me.

Comment: I can't put a breakpoint in the Word.Table tbl = oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref Index).Range.Tables[1] line

Comment: Click anywhere on this line and press F9. Run the program with F5. The program will stop at this line and you can inspect the values of the variables. (Inspect the values of `oWordDoc.Bookmarks` and `.Range.Tables` especially. They must not be `null` or empty.)